# Invalid credentials raises exception on auth mutation

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-django

I'm using graphene-django and django-graphql-jwt in my django project. When I set invalid credentials server raises 'Invalid credentials' exception.

Are invalid credentials supposed to raise an exception on the server? When I test tokenAuth mutation with wrong data Django server raises exception.

Django server log:

```
  File "/Users/cgf/.local/share/virtualenvs/testdjangoauthbackend-183R1gMP/lib/python3.7/site-packages/promise/promise.py", line 487, in _resolve_from_executor
    executor(resolve, reject)
  File "/Users/cgf/.local/share/virtualenvs/testdjangoauthbackend-183R1gMP/lib/python3.7/site-packages/promise/promise.py", line 754, in executor
    return resolve(f(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/cgf/.local/share/virtualenvs/testdjangoauthbackend-183R1gMP/lib/python3.7/site-packages/graphql/execution/middleware.py", line 75, in make_it_promise
    return next(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/cgf/.local/share/virtualenvs/testdjangoauthbackend-183R1gMP/lib/python3.7/site-packages/graphql_jwt/decorators.py", line 106, in wrapper
    result = f(cls, root, info, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/cgf/.local/share/virtualenvs/testdjangoauthbackend-183R1gMP/lib/python3.7/site-packages/graphql_jwt/decorators.py", line 89, in wrapper
    _('Please, enter valid credentials'))
graphql.error.located_error.GraphQLLocatedError: Please, enter valid credentials
```

Answer (score 2):

I also experienced the same thing. Actually they are showing the stack trace intentionally. I think, this issue will be resolved soon. Check out [`this thread`](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphql-core/issues/41) for the details.

Answer (score 1):

[django-graphql-auth](https://github.com/pedrobern/django-graphql-auth/) extends django-graphql-jwt to add more features, like registration, email verification...

One of the advantages is that it returns a standard output, containing `success` and `errors`.

For example, instead of raising an error, like in `django-graphql-jwt` for invalid credentials, it return:

```
{
  "data": {
    "tokenAuth": {
      "success": false,
      "errors": {
        "nonFieldErrors": [
          {
            "message": "Please, enter valid credentials.",
            "code": "invalid_credentials"
          }
        ]
      },
      "token": null,
      "refreshToken": null,
      "unarchiving": false,
      "user": null
    }
  }
}
```